# Construction of a line segment with ruler only

Tags: geometry

We have piece of paper with a point P and two line segments on it. The lines fit on the line segments intersect at a point off of the paper (call it Q). How do I construct, with a (long enough) ruler only, the segment of the PQ line that is on the piece of sheet?

Comment: What kind of constructions can you carry out with your ruler?

Comment: @Aretino you can make sections longer (e.g. reach the edges of the paper), the usual kind of things but you can't measure length

Answer (score 1):

[Pappus’ theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus's_hexagon_theorem) will do the trick. Referring to this image from the Wikipedia page:

[image]

let $X$ the given point $P$ on the paper, $Z$ be the point of intersection $Q$ that’s off the paper, and $BZ$, $bZ$ be the given lines. Choose a point $A$ on the paper so that the line $AX$ intersects $bZ$, then choose another point $a$ such that $aX$ intersects $BZ$. It’s often convenient to choose these points so that they’re on opposite sides of the two given lines. Now, construct in turn the lines $AB$, $ab$, $Ac$ and $aC$. Let $Y$ be the point of intersection of $Ac$ and $aC$. The points $X$ (=$P$), $Y$ and $Z$ (=$Q$) are colinear.  You might have to play around with the locations of $A$ and $a$ a bit to get everything to fit on the paper.